# Requirements to learn Draco Meteor

Tags: pokemon-black-white

I have all eight badges in Pokemon White, and my lead Pokemon is a Zweilous. The friendship checker in Icirrus City says, "It is super friendly to you! I'm a bit jealous!" However, when I talk to Drayden in Opelucid City he doesn't offer to teach it Draco Meteor.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to beat the Elite Four/The Champion in order for Drayden to teach you Draco Meteor.